# Running OpenFlow on a PC?

Tags: openflow

I have a question about the running of OpenFlow switch:
If we want to  run OpenFlow on such a PC or a router  to work as an OpenFlow switch,  what should we do for that?, and is the  CPU type or platform  of that device important? does  it make any difference?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Before you try anything on a PC, Install Open vSwitch on a VM(probably Ubuntu) and try its OpenFlow functionality.

To install Open vSwitch(OVS) on ubuntu,

> sudo apt-get install openvswitch-switch

You could get a controller like [Floodlight](http://www.projectfloodlight.org/floodlight/) or [Ryu SDN framework](http://osrg.github.io/ryu/) to act as the controller for your switch.

Here is an OpenFlow tutorial. It is outdated but still informative http://archive.openflow.org/wk/index.php/OpenFlow_Tutorial

Or you could also try mininet as @EricSorensen suggested in the previous answer. Mininet allows you to simulate a network with hosts and switches.
While using mininet, you could use its inbuilt 'nox' controller. I'd prefer floodlight though.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need: http://mininet.org/
Check the downloads and tutorial. Use either a Virtual Machine, or native install from source (on Linux)

Comment: @user3201263 please confirm the answer if you find it acceptable

Answer (score 0):

you can install openvswitch or use ofsoftswitch13 from *https://github.com/CPqD/ofsoftswitch13* in a linux based PC with at least two physical interfaces.so that the packet routing can see.

Also using mininet *https://github.com/mininet/mininet* can run OF (for this one interface is enough) which supports the creation of various network topologies.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested for testing you can simply do a apt-get install or similar on most recent Linux distros. There are two components to openvswitch, a kernel module and the user space openvswitch. The user space process does not require any specific number of cores or processor type and for the most part you can do with less than a core.

Apart from ovs you also need ovsdb, which apt-get install or similar will automatically set up for you (hence the easiest way to go about it). Again pretty lightweight its just a json key-value db.

For the controller there are a lot of options but for playing around you can use the built in command line tools as well.

ovs-apptctl: To setup the switch http://openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-appctl.8.txt

ovs-oftcl: To add/mod/flows http://openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-ofctl.8.txt

ovs-dpctl: To see the kernel flows

I would highly recommend getting a feel for the command line tools, OpenFlow commands and how flows work before picking Pox, Daylight etc.

Apart from mininet there is also Oftest (https://github.com/floodlight/oftest) that is primarily used to write tests for openflow but its pretty useful to learn and debug issues in a constrained environment.

Answer (score 0):

Running OpenvSwitch

If you want to build OpenvSwitch with bare metal, I suggest you use official tarball to install OpenvSwitch daemon.
Please follow this step:

```
#/bin/bash
# In root permission
aptitude install dh-autoreconf libssl-dev openssl
wget http://openvswitch.org/releases/openvswitch-2.4.0.tar.gz
tar zxvf openvswitch-2.4.0.tar.gz && cd openvswitch-2.4.0
./boot.sh
./configure # If you want to build kernel module, please append --with-linux=/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build
make modules_install
modprobe gre
modprobe openvswitch
modprobe livcrc32c
ovsdb-tool create /usr/local/etc/openvswitch/conf.db /usr/local/share/openvswitch/vswitch.ovsschema
ovsdb-server --remote=punix:/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock \
--remote=db:Open_vSwitch,Open_vSwitch,manager_options \
--pidfile --detach --log-file
ovs-vsctl --no-wait init
ovs-vswitchd --pidfile --detach --log-file
```

You can use `ovs-vsctl show` of `ovs-ofctl show` to check OpenvSwitch status. Next step, we need to add physical or logical (likes veth pair) interfaces to OpenvSwitch bridge

```
# Create OpenvSwitch is named 'ovs-br'
ovs-vsctl add-br ovs-br

# Add interface to OpenvSwitch bridge
# If you want to check, please use `ovs-vsctl` to check again.    
ovs-vsctl add-port ovs-br eth0

# Set OpenFlow controller
# You should ready one controller
# If not, I have two installation solutions can give you
# Ryu installation: https://github.com/sdnds-tw/ryu-installer
# ONOS installation: https://github.com/pichuang/onos-ansible
ovs-vsctl ovs-br set-controller tcp:x.x.x.x:6653

# Use ovs-vsctl to check controller attribute is UP
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you let another server(here we call it controller) to determine the packet forwarding behavior of your local machine (here it is your PC), it turns into so-called SDN mechanism. So it's not relevant what kind of CPU or hardware you are choosing, basically, you can consider SDN as a software solution.

For the process to install the SDN-enabled software, you can choose open vswitch which has been answered in the above posts.